# Error passing values into array/values in array missing

Tags: c++

I have a text file and I passed it to a char array. It was fine when I display in a getline() loop but after going through encryption, only the last line is encrypted and displayed. I have tried to display values in array before entering shift key and what is inside the array is the last line of the text only. What has went wrong? Please help!!

```
char msg[5000];
string plaintext;
int choice, shift;
char ch;

// Read file into char array
ifstream infile("plaintext.txt");
while (getline(infile, plaintext))
{
    strcpy_s(msg, plaintext.c_str());
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << msg[i];
    }
}

cout << endl;
cout << "Enter shift key: ";
cin >> shift;                           //take the shift as input
cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
cout << "1.Encryption" << endl;
cout << "2.Decryption" << endl;
cin >> choice;

// Encryption
if (choice == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        ch = msg[i];
        //encrypt for lowercase letter
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            ch = ch + shift;
            if (ch > 'z') {
                ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            msg[i] = ch;
        }
        //encrypt for uppercase letter
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            ch = ch + shift;
            if (ch > 'Z') {
                ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            msg[i] = ch;
        }
    }
    printf("Encrypted message: %s", msg);

}
```

**result**

[image]

Comment: When you deal with C-style strings, but  really want byte arrays, then `\0` is going to ruin your day.

Comment: With `strcpy` you overwrite every time the `msg` array. Use `strcat` instead to append the plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong because you need to use `strcat` too

```
// Read file into char array
ifstream infile("plaintext.txt");
while (getline(infile, plaintext))
{
    strcpy_s(msg, plaintext.c_str());
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << msg[i];
    }
}
```

Instead:

```
// Read file into char array
ifstream infile("plaintext.txt");
getline(infile, plaintext)

if (!plaintext.empty())
{
    strcpy_s(msg, plaintext.c_str());

    plaintext.clear();

    while (getline(infile, plaintext))
    {
        strcat_s(msg, sizeof msg, plaintext.c_str());

        for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++)
        {
            cout << msg[i];
        }

        plaintext.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work but I have figured out. Instead of plaintext.size(), it should be size of array. Thanks for your help! :D